# I can't get to return more than one item when using webservices GetListItems

Tags: 2007, jquery

But i have an issue though it only returns one record while there are more than one item in the list.
Any ideas i did increased the row limit but no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") +  "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").html(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});</script><ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><RowLimit>0</RowLimit>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") +  "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").html(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});</script><ul id="tasksUL"/>
```